# How can I send email asynchronously from a MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, sendasync

In my MVC 3 Razor application, an **ActionResult Create()** method in the Controller handles a user HttpPost. At that point:

1. Data is saved to a database.
2. Emails are sent to interested parties using another project in the solution.
3. A Confirmation page is served back to the user.

Since emailing is the most time-consuming activity, I'm attempting to use **SmtpClient.SendAsync()**, rather than **SmtpClient().Send**.

Is this scenario possible if inheritance is from AsyncController? Can anyone provide an example?

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely check out [MVC Mailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide). Very nice tool to create emails with razor views. It has an option to send mails asynchronously. MVC mailer is also available via nuget.

Comment: +1 as they have some great docs (especially the unit testing part)

Comment: I just stumbled upon MvcMailer, and WOW...that stuff should have been baked into MVC3, instead of the crappy WebMail helper methods that just recreate SmtpClient as a static class.  Kudos for MvcMailer!  +1 for this recommendation.